# How to link a database to Google Visualization API to display a chart?

Tags: database, charts, google-visualization

Can anyone tell me how to link a database to Google Visualization API to display a chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either have a php file pass the data to your page, or have an Ajax call get the data.